# How to keep List's scrolling position?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Look at this code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    TabView {
        List {
                ForEach((0...99), id: \.self) {Text("\($0)")}
             }
              .tabItem {
                    Text("tab 1")
                }
        Text("tab 2")
        .tabItem {
                Text("tab 2")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

So I run this app, scroll a list view a bit, then I tap on a **tab 2** and back on **tab 1**. Boom! List view is not scrolled. I understand why this is happened: List is recreated once again. But I would like to keep List's scrolling position during tapping on TabView. Any ideas?

Comment: I run your code and follow you steps list is scrolling @Yury

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav I mean - List view does not keep its scrolling position. It always reset it at list's start.

Comment: hi @yury, one approach is just use `.contentOffset`   Perhaps save it as you change screens and set it as you return to a screen.  Use animnated "false" of course.  Hope it helps!

Comment: that's why I continue using UIKit but declarative way with UIKitPlus library